# How to write stored procedure for getting top record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I write a SQL stored procedure for getting top n records from stored procedure?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetRe
     (@a INT, @b INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sum INT
    SET @Sum = @a + @B

    SELECT TOP @Sum * 
    FROM Customer
END
```

I'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@Sum'

Comment: What database are you using?   you'll likely need a ; after the declare, set, and select lines

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks like you’re using SQL Server.

You need to wrap the `@Sum` in parenthesis:

```
SELECT TOP (@Sum) * 
FROM Customer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..But plz Help me y we need 2 write CTE Table already we hav sql querys

Comment: @MdGhousemohi I’m not sure what that has to do with the question.  If you have a new question, please make a new post.  That’s a bit much to address in the comments, and it’s not relevant to this question.